# What is difference between shell and eshell in emacs?

Tags: shell, emacs, sudo, eshell

What is the difference between eshell (M-x eshell) and shell (M-x shell) in emacs. Both seems to work same but when i try to run su command or sudo command in eshell then it create a buffer named tramp/su root:localhost. but don't do the work which i want to do as super user.

Comment: Sorry, not a programming question, please try  http://superuser.com/ . (I didn't downvote your question). Good luck.

Answer (score 17):

In short [`eshell`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryEshell) is a shell emulator (written in Emacs-Lisp), while [`shell`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellMode) is an interface to `sh` or whatever (external) system shell you're using.

`eshell` should behave like most "Bourne-style" shells that you're familiar with, but does not have the external dependency that `shell` has.  Thus, it can be run on any system that runs emacs.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. Please answer me another question which i have described in question body.

Comment: @msankhala, eshell uses several builtin commands, sudo is one of them. To use system's sudo, try `*sudo command`.